# PDF Merger using php

Tags: php, pdf

I am working on a project in which I have to merge multiple pdf files into one.

I create one using fdpi pdf merger but it has a problem saying 'Trailer keyword not found after xref table'.

I looked on google it says I have to uncompress each pdf individually first using [this website](https://docupub.com/pdfconvert/) to merge them.

Can anyone provide php script for uncompress any pdf to pdf 1.7 or provide another pdf merger which merge multiple pdf into one without any version?

```
    <?php
include 'PDFMerger.php';

if(isset($_FILES) && !empty($_FILES)){


if(count($_FILES['file']['name'])) {
    foreach ($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] as $each_file) {


        $files_array[] = $each_file;
    }

    $pdf = new PDFMerger;
    for ($i=0; $i<count($files_array); $i++){
      $pdf->addPDF($files_array[$i], 'all');
    }

    $pdf->merge('browser', 'samplepdfs/TEST2.pdf');
}
}
?>

<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row marg-top-double">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <input type="file" name="file[]" multiple>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row marg-top-double">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <input name="sub_btn" type="submit" value="Upload" multiple class="btn btn-default">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

above code gives following error, FPDF error: Trailer keyword not found after xref table

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far?

Comment: @MichaelDotKnox i edited my post please check it out.

Comment: above code gives following error, FPDF error: Trailer keyword not found after xref table

Comment: Any chance you show the PDF in question, that produces this error?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using FPDF to do merge the files together, it apparently has problems with some PDF files that are created by some programs such as Microsoft Word.  In some cases, these programs add additional information such as a signature in the properties of the document.

Editing the PDF file in Adobe Acrobat or Adobe Illustrator might resolve the problem.

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36807973/5106565) which provides some more insight and [this article](http://www.vankouteren.eu/blog/2009/07/fpdf-error-unable-to-find-xref-table/) which provides some more explanation.

Comment: thanks for the reply i agree with you but i can't edit every file individually as i have thousands of files to merge together. do you know any other way to do that.

Comment: The other stackoverflow answer has some pretty good solutions that will probably work.  I'm not very familiar with the pdf libraries so I can't say what will work, but I think it is probably just a matter of getting the correct libraries into play.

Comment: @zaib You got the solution for this mate using PDF merge only or you opted for some other library.

Answer (score 0):

We've found with similar PDF libraries (mPDF) that regressing the files to PDF ~v1.4 helps with merging; see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40702177/427847